# Need help adding a standard drop down box to my simple web application in ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, html.dropdownlistfor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have created a simple web app, using ASP.NET Core MVC architecture, to convert units of measurement to other units of measurement. For example, Fahrenheit to Celsius, MilesPerHour to KilometersPerHour, etc. I am using a binding model to pass into the various action methods, pull the user input from forms and bind them to the binding model, then create a local view model to take the input from the binding model and convert it to the new UnitOf type, then return the view model.

For one of my inputs, I am trying to use a standard drop down box. I am having trouble getting the drop down box to appear on the rendered HTML index page. Here is what I have done thus far to do so.

I have created an IndexViewModel to hold the IEnumerable property, as well as a String SelectedItem property. (Since I am not allowed to embed images in my posts yet, I am unsure if you can see the screenshots through the links or not. Although I am not new to using StackOverflow, I am new to posting questions.)

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public String SelectedMph { get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MilesPerHourList { get; set;}
}
```

I then added a private method to populate the IEnumerable Items object to the controller.

```
 private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetMphs()
    {
        return new SelectListItem[]
        {
            new SelectListItem() {Text="5",Value = "5"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text="25",Value = "25"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text="50",Value="50"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text="100",Value="100"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text="500",Value="500" }
        };
    }
```

I then updated my Index() action method to create an instance of IndexViewModel(), called the private method to populate the IEnumerable on that instance, and then returned that instance in a View(indexViewModel).

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IndexViewModel index = new IndexViewModel
        {
            MilesPerHourList = GetMphs()
        };
        return View(index);
    }
```

Next, I need to add the appropriate markup to the index.cshtml page using the appropriate tag helpers for the drop down box. I have tried variations of the @Html command and couldn't get it to show on the index page. The latest attempt was to use the <drop-down-list tag with the asp-for and asp-items tag helpers.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Conversions" asp-action="MphToKph">
        <drop-down-list asp-for="SelectedMph" asp-items="Model.MilesPerHourList">
            MilesPerHour
        </drop-down-list>
        <button type="submit" name="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I will worry about the model binding for this particular action method once I can get the drop down box showing. If anyone could please help with what I have done wrong thus far, or a solution that will get the drop down box visible on the index page. Thank you.

Comment: Images of code are not accepted here. Either edit the code into your question so that others can copy it to run it, or the question WILL be closed.

Comment: okay, images have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<select></select>`.Here is a demo:

```
@model IndexViewModel
<div class="form-group">
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Conversions" asp-action="MphToKph">
        <select asp-for="SelectedMph" asp-items="Model.MilesPerHourList">
            MilesPerHour
        </select>
        <button type="submit" name="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: That along with moving my IEnumerable<SelectListItem> property to the view model. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I developed in case anyone else has a similar problem:

Index method inside controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ConversionsViewModel conversionModel = new ConversionsViewModel();
        return View(conversionModel);                    
    }
```

IEnumerable Mphs inside View Model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Mphs { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{Value="5",Text="5"},
        new SelectListItem{Value="25",Text="25"},
        new SelectListItem{Value="50", Text="50"},
        new SelectListItem{Value="100",Text="100"},
        new SelectListItem{Value="250",Text="250"}

    };
```

Select tag inside index.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Conversions" asp-action="MphToKph">
        <label asp-for="MilesPerHour"><em>MilesPerHour To KilometersPerHour</em></label>
        <select asp-for="MilesPerHour" asp-items="Model.Mphs" name="Input"
                size="1"></select>
        <button type="submit" name="submitButton">Submit</button>
        <span asp-validation-for="MilesPerHour"></span>

    </form>
</div>
```